# compile ffmpeg decode only without audio codecs

Tags: vb.net, windows, video, ffmpeg, visual-studio-2015

I work on a media manager and use ffmpeg.exe to extract screenshots.
With the latest size of ffmpeg.exe exceeding 35MB, I am attempting to build ffmpeg without the majority of its functions, to allow only saving of a frame of video.

I had thought disabling many of the filters, Audio Codecs etc would shrink the size of ffmpeg to something more manageable.

Following this guide 
https://pracucci.com/compile-ffmpeg-on-windows-with-visual-studio-compiler.html
to allow building of ffmpeg using Visual Studio 2015, I have come to the part of ./configuration   and hit a wall.
With so many options and no idea what all of them mean or do, I am asking if someone in the community can give me laymans instructions.

I also know that I need to build x264, and possible x265 (HEVC), but am not sure if there is anything other codecs needed.
In the end, I and am hoping to just have the one file, ffmpeg.exe for use in the media manager project.

The code I use to get a screenshot is as follows

```
Public Shared Function CreateScreenShot(ByVal FullPathAndFilename As String, ByVal SavePath As String, ByVal sec As Integer, Optional ByVal Overwrite As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    If Not File.Exists(SavePath) Or Overwrite Then
        Try
            IO.File.Delete(SavePath)
        Catch
            Return False
        End Try
        If IO.File.Exists(FullPathAndFilename) Then
            Dim myProcess As Process = New Process
            Try
                Dim seconds As Integer = sec
                myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Utilities.applicationPath & "\Assets\ffmpeg.exe"
                Dim proc_arguments As String = "-ss " & seconds.ToString & " -i """ & FullPathAndFilename & """ -vframes:v 1 -an " & """" & SavePath & """"
                myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = proc_arguments
                myProcess.Start()
                myProcess.WaitForExit()
                If File.Exists(SavePath) Then Return True
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            Finally
                myProcess.Close()
            End Try
        End If
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

I hope this is sufficient information, and appreciated any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option `--disable-everything` which will disable all components without enabling explicitly.

I guess you may try to build it with:

```
./configure --disable-everything --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --toolchain=msvc --enable-yasm --enable-asm
```

If there is any other codecs needed, they should be added to the option too.

And if some ffmpeg libs are not needed, they can be disabled like:

```
./configure --disable-postproc
```

See the `Component options` part in `./configure --help` output for how to disable/enable those libs.

Comment: So I just need to find a list of video codecs and add --enable-<codecnamehere>  What about -enable-static, will that give all dependencies in the one ffmpeg.exe file?

Comment: @Rob Yes. Static build will link those `libav*` and other libs into the executable file. While `--enable-shared` will give you a small executable about several hundreds KBs and some other libs add up to dozens of MBs which still be needed when running. If you want a minimal static build, you may disable some libs too. I've updated the answer.